# Deserialize JSON using Newtonsoft in C#

Tags: serialization

I am having a heck of a time converting JSON.  Tried a dozen stackoverflow solutions, but still stuck.  I am connecting to an API and getting JSON data in the format below.  The goal is to get a list of Firstname, Lastname and street addresses of the homeowners parsed from the JSON collection.  I built a simple utility to try and sort this out.  I paste JSON in the top textbox and results appear in the bottom textbox.

```
        JSON data:
[
  {
    "HomeOwnerFirstName": "Elizabeth",
    "HomeOwnerLastName": "Jones",
    "PropertyAddress": "123 AnyStreet",
  },
  {
    "HomeOwnerFirstName": "Bob",
    "HomeOwnerLastName": "Smith",
    "PropertyAddress": "345 AnyStreet",
  }
]

        

    public class Homeowners
    {
        public string HomeOwnerFirstName { get; set; }
        public string HomeOwnerLastName { get; set; }
        public string PropertyAddress { get; set; }
     }
             private void cmdDeserial_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //deserialize by using JSON in Top textbox
    {
        desiraliseJSON(txtInput.Text);
    }
    
    private void desiraliseJSON(string strJSON)
    {
        try
        {
            var jsondata = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Homeowners>>(strJSON);
            txtBox2.Text = jsondata.ToString();  //Show the deserialized text in the bottom textbox.
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            txtBox2.Text = ("Error: " + ex.Message.ToString());

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I finally found the problem and fixed it.  I was trying to deserialize based on internal JSON values instead of a class (group) of them

So changing the try/catch to:

```
try
{
    var homeowner = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Homeowners[]>(strJSON);
        foreach var (account in homeowner)
        {
                txtBox2.Text = (account.HomeOwnerLastName + ", " + account.PropertyAddress + "     Balance: " + account.Balance);
        }
    
}
```

allowed it to iterate through the lines and produce the right results.